# Accessing jQuery method when using [i]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to modify the CSS properties of `elementDiv` using jQuery. I understand that when using `[i]` I am getting a DOM element and not a jQuery object. Can this be modified to accept the jQuery CSS method?

The following code returns the following error - `Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'css'`

```
for (var i = 0; i < elementDiv.length; i++) {
    if (i >= pagenumber * elementsPerPage && i <= pagenumber * elementsPerPage) {
        elementDiv[i].css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        elementDiv[i].css('display', 'none');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
elementDiv.each(function(i) {
  if (i >= pagenumber * elementsPerPage && i <= pagenumber * elementsPerPage) {
      $(this).css('display', 'block');
  } else {
      $(this).css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

The jQuery docs show a lot of useful examples.

Comment: `.each()` vs. the `for` loop is not the issue here - you could use either and it would make no difference. What _is_ different in your code is that it wraps the HTML element reference (`this` in your code) inside `$()`. OP's code did not do that. It would work equally well to use `$(elementDiv[i])` in OP's code. I'm not suggesting whether `.each()` or the `for` loop is better than the other, only that they aren't relevant to the problem here, and it's always good to recognize the actual problem and not mix it up with something else.